# Model fields won't appear through Django development server. How do I fix it?

Tags: python, django

I am following the Tech With Tim Django + React tutorial (although naming some variables differently)(https://youtu.be/uhSmgR1hEwg) and ran into a problem with views when running the server. My urls work properly but when I go onto the page **I can't find any of my model fields**. I am new to Django and VSCode (having mostly only used PyCharm in the past) so it may end up being a very simple solution. Here is my code and directories:

[Directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTWuQ.png)

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
import string
import random


def generate_unique_code():
    length = 6

    while True:
        code = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase, k=length))
        if Room.objects.filter(code=code).count() == 0:
            break

    return code

class Room(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=8, default="", unique=True)
    host = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    guest_can_pause = models.BooleanField(null=False, default=False)
    votes_to_skip = models.IntegerField(null=False, default=1)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

---

**serializers.py:**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Room


class RoomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Room
        fields = '__all__'
```

---

**urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import RoomView

urlpatterns = [
    path('home', RoomView.as_view()),
]
```

---

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import generics
from .serializers import RoomSerializer
from .models import Room


class RoomView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Room.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RoomSerializer
```

---

**urls.py:**

```
"""URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('api.urls'))
]
```

[Incorrect output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTOjU.png)
[Incorrect output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqLUj.png)

I have gone back through the code I am working off of multiple times, looked through the Django documentation for any updates that could have broken it and have been unable to find any solutions.

Comment: Likely your database is just still empty, so there is no data to return.

Comment: Could you explain? I have my fields in the model so fields should appear when running the server.

Comment: @Venzio: well there are columns, but no records (rows).

Answer (score 0):

The database is just *empty*. Indeed, if there is data in the database, it will produce a list where each key is mapped to a value, like:

```
[{
    "code": val11,
    "host": val12,
    "guest_can_pause": val13,
    "votes_to_skip": val14,
    "created_at": val15
}, {
    "code": val21,
    "host": val22,
    "guest_can_pause": val23,
    "votes_to_skip": val24,
    "created_at": val25
}, /* … */ {
    "code": valn1,
    "host": valn2,
    "guest_can_pause": valn3,
    "votes_to_skip": valn4,
    "created_at": valn5
}]
```

If there are however no records, it will produce a list, an empty one. The columns are there in the database, but since there are no rows, there is no data to serialize, and thus no keys appear.

But you can *fill* the database with data. For example manually with SQL queries, or through the Django ORM, or Django's admin site, if you use that one.

If there is data, the data will eventually get serialized, so the columns will appear in the database.